# Keyboard window key button - onkeypress or onkeyup - not able to prevent default event

Tags: javascript

I try to prevent all keyboard keys events (onkeypress or onkeyup or onkeydown), it is working for all keyboard keys except window key. my aim is to disable all keys and its events in website , only mouse can be used.

Please find the code below. awaiting for better solution.

```
<script>
    var body = document.querySelector('body');

    body.onkeydown = function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    };

    body.onkeypress = function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    };

    body.onkeyup = function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    };
 </script>
```

Thanks :) ...

Comment: I don't think disabling the Windows key is possible. Its function is handled way outside the browser scope.

Comment: You cannot preventDefault of system functions. Same applies to key combinations like ctrl + alt + delete.

Comment: Thanks. any other solution is there ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, You can call  `onload()` function in body it will disable all your keys.

**For example** i am disabling keys only in this `textarea`

```js
$("textarea").keydown(false);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea rows=3 cols=20></textarea>​
```